# How do I do reflexive self-join relationships in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, social-networking, self-join

I'm trying to implement a social networking style friendship model and I didnt have much much luck trying to figure out the plugins available out there. I think I'll learn Rails better if I do it myself. So here's what I have :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invitee_friendships ,
           :foreign_key => :friend_id,
           :class_name => 'Friendship'

  has_many :inviter_friends,
            :through => :invitee_friendships

  has_many :inviter_friendships ,
           :foreign_key => :user_id,
           :class_name => 'Friendship'

  has_many :invited_friends,
            :through => :inviter_friendships

end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  //I think something needs to come here, i dont know what
end
```

In `irb` when I try this:

```
friend1  = Friend.create(:name => 'Jack')
friend2  = Friend.create(:name => 'John')
bff = Friendship.create(:user_id =>1, :friend_id => 2)
f1.invited_friends
```

I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError:
Could not find the source
association(s) :invited_friend or
:invited_friends in model Friendship. 
Try 'has_many :invited_friends,
:through => :invited_friendships,
:source => <name>'.  Is it one of
:user?
```

**Expanation of friendship system:**

- A user can invite other users to become friends.
- Users who you invited to become friends are represented by `invited_friends`.
- Users who invited you to become friends are represented by `inviter_friends`.
- Your total friend list is represented by `invited_friends` + `inviter_friends`.

**Schema**

```
table Friendship
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :friend_id
      t.boolean :invite_accepted
      t.timestamps

table User
    t.string :name
    t.string :description
```

Comment: Pls provide the complete schema. The plugin rake task Annotate Models -- http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2006/02/annotate_models.html and http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/annotate_models -- is very helpful for this. It documents the models' schemas as comments in the model files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has pointed to the recent Ryan Bates's [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) on the topic :)

Hope this helps!.

Excerpt from Ryan '... requires a self-referential association on the User model to define friends/followers'